# Is Drow Elf a terrible race choice for Tales of the Yawning Portal?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, tales-from-the-yawning-portal

My friend is going to GM Tales of the Yawning Portal hardcover and I am thinking about making a Drow character. However, I am worried about their Sunlight Sensitivity feature and how it'll affect my build that is dependent on getting Advantage a lot.

How prominent is the Sun in this adventure? Is picking Drow for an elf race going to be fine or am I gonna have a bad time?

---

Also, please don't spoil the adventure.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, you won’t have much trouble with the Drow’s Sunlight Sensitivity while playing the adventures of Tales of the Yawning Portal. This is because the book is an assortment of seperate dungeons, all of which are subterranean, and thereby avoiding direct sunlight during the vast majority of combat encounters.

Answer (score 4):

*Tales* isn't a single adventure. Per the back cover, it's 7 independent dungeons. Having run the first two and glanced at some of the rest, I don't think you'll have any trouble as a Drow.

Comment: Why don't you think they'll have any trouble playing a drow? This is a very short answer that doesn't explain anything and we require answers to be backed up with citations and/or experience . What was your experience as it relates to the question when running the first two adventures? What about the adventures makes you think playing a drow isn't going to be an issue? Please expand your answer and explain your reasoning.

Comment: Difficulty playing a traditionally evil race will also largely depend on the setting and how the DM runs the NPCs with which the PCs interact.

Comment: +1: OP specifically asked for no spoilers, so lack of detail here is more appropriate

Comment: @DanB: This answer doesn't justify itself at all. Even if OP doesn't want any spoilers, without some sort of supporting explanation, another answer saying "You will have lots of trouble as a drow; don't pick it" without explanation would be essentially equivalent to this. All answers need to be supported by citing evidence or experience; it should generally be possible to explain any problems (or lack thereof) without spoilers, and even if spoilers are necessary, [StackExchange has spoiler-tag formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1191/335251).